# Simplification of a symbolic manipulation involving functions of more than one variable

Tags: symbolic

I am facing the following  problem.

```
f[x_,y_] = a[x] u[y] + b[x] v[y]
```

Now I can ask Mathematica to calculate

```
g[x_] = Integrate[ Expand[f[x,y]^2],y]
```

which it correctly shows. In the expansion we have 
an expression like

```
Integrate[ a[x]^2 u[y]^2 + 2 a[x] b[x] u[v] v[y] + b[x]^2 v[y]^2 , y]
```

Now in the output I want to replace

```
Integrate[u[y]^2,y]
```

by `I11` etc. Using `/.` did not do the job. Can anyone please enlighten me?

Comment: Huh? There's no `Integrate[u[y]^2,y]` in `Integrate[ a[x]^2 u[y]^2 + 2 a[x] b[x] u[v] v[y] + b[x]^2 v[y]^2 , y]`...

Comment: Your question is not very clear... can you show what you tried with `/.`?

Comment: OK - I will post the complete code here a I am posting from a different machine. I am also baffled why the a[x] is not being dragged out of the integral. Where I am making the error? I must confess that I have used mathematica till now as ODE solver and for calculus and plotting. This is completely a new domain for me and thus please be patient. Thanks!

Comment: @J.M. There is, provided you assume that `x` is independent of `y`, then `Integrate[a[x]^2 u[y]^2, y] == a[x]^2 Integrate[u[y]^2, y]`. (Also, threading over the sum.) Not that Mathematica knows that.

Comment: @rcollyer: `Integrate[]` is very cautious that way...

Comment: When how do I tell mathematica that x is independent of y?

Comment: @J.M. and reasonably so.

Answer (score 4):

The main difficulty here is that `Integrate` does not normally thread over addition. In other words, it does not understand that

$$\int f(x) + g(x) \text{d}x = \int f(x) \text{d}x + \int g(x) \text{d}x.$$

In most cases, it is true, but as integration is a limiting process care must be taken in the order of operations. A case where that is not true does not come to mind at the moment, other than involving [infinite series](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/31581/2283), but it is not out of the question that a simplification in the integrand could obscure the relationship between the LHS and RHS, above.  Mathematica, however, *does* understand

$$\int a(x) f(y) \text{d}y = a(x) \int f(y) \text{d}y,$$

as shown by

```
Integrate[a[x] u[y], y]
(*
 a[x] Integrate[u[y], y]
*)
```

A method to achieve the form you are looking for is to `Map` `Integrate` across the sum, `Expand[f[x,y]^2]`, as follows

```
ints = Integrate[#, y]& /@ Expand[f[x,y]^2]
(*
  a[x]^2*Integrate[u[y]^2, y] + 2*a[x]*b[x]*Integrate[u[y]*v[y], y] 
+ b[x]^2*Integrate[v[y]^2, y]
*)
```

Then, `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) works just fine,

```
ints /. Integrate[u[y]^2, y] -> I11
(*
  I11*a[x]^2 + 2*a[x]*b[x]*Integrate[u[y]*v[y], y] 
+ b[x]^2*Integrate[v[y]^2, y]
*)
```

Comment: One problem with expanding a sum under an integral is that if the summands depend on different parameters, there could be _conditions_ generated - and those could be different for different terms in the sum. But that could make it hard to deduce the combined condition of validity for the entire integral.

Comment: @Jens, absolutely, and as such my method above needs to be used with caution.

Comment: +1. It is actually easy to construct a case when threading over addition is not correct: any integral which is finite but where the integrand is a difference of 2 terms where each term individually would lead to a divergent integral.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin that was actually the case that was coming to mind, but in some sense that case is reversing the order of two limiting processes with which care must be taken.

Comment: You can also have cancellations of divergent terms for integrals over finite intervals, if infinite limits are what you had in mind as one of the limiting processes.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin it was one form, yes. However, integration itself (like differentiation) is a limiting process, so any time you mix that with potentially divergent terms, then you can run into problems. Limits are an area where order of operations matters very much, and their naive application (like we do all the time) implies that order is not relevant, except when it becomes so. :)

Comment: @rcollyer "Limits are an area where order of operations matters very much" - tell me about that, my Ph.D. was on some aspects of anomalies (particularly Chiral Anomaly) and effects related to spontaneous breaking of Chiral Symmetry in QFT :). I meant that, for divergent integral over a finite interval, you have only one limit, which is the one of Darboux (or Riemann) sums, used in the definition of the (Riemann) integral.  You have two limits when your integral is improper, which is what I assume you meant.